# Swagger docs upload binary file not correct curl command in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, swagger, swagger-2.0

Creating a Swagger doc for my api endpoints. I have a curl command that works in the terminal

```
curl -X POST -b "http://localhost:3000/v0/users/4/avatar" -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" -F avatar=@wolf.b64
```

What this returns is an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object from rails.

However, my swagger doc curl command looks like this

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/v0/users/4/avatar" -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" -F avatar=wolf.b64
```

The avatar param doesn't start with `@` which makes it only a string instead of a file.

I need help figuring out how to setup swagger so that @ is added in front of the file name.

This is what my Swagger looks like.

```
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "user"
    ],
    "description": "Update user",
    "operationId": "updateUser",
    "produces": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "consumes": [
      "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "userId",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "ID of the user that needs to be updated",
        "required": true,
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int64"
      },
      {
        "name": "avatar",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "Base64 encoded image upload",
        "required": true,
        "type": "file"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "The user avatars was successfully updated"
      },
      "401": {
        "description": "Unauthorized"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Your spec looks correct. Which version of Swagger UI are you using? (2.x / 3.0.x)

Comment: I'm using Swagger v2. How do you check what version swagger-UI is?
Under swagger-ui.js.map it says version: 3. Under swagger-ui-bundler.js it says version 2.4.0

Comment: @Helen is there a specific version that will return `avatar=@wolf.b64` as a call?

Comment: UI 3.x looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhr9e.png), 2.x - [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAuBp.png). I'm not sure, but this seems to be a bug in Swagger UI. You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/new) in its GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks @Helen I've opened an issue.. Hopefully someone gets back to me.